Determine number of merge records instead of records in Data Source
I have the below code which I got from this site and it produces individual PDFs.  When it runs it cycles through all merge records in the Data Source.  The issue I have is that we apply a filter when opening and it may only select say 10 records of the total data source of 200 records.  Is there a way to determine the number of merge records (e.g. 10) instead of using datasource.RecordCount which returns 200.  The issue is that it continues to cycle through the entire Data Source which takes longer compared to just the actual records being merged.
Public Sub Merge_To_Individual_Files()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim StrFolder As String, StrName As String, MainDoc As Document, i As Long, j As Long
Const StrNoChr As String = """*./\:?|"
Set MainDoc = ActiveDocument
With MainDoc
  StrFolder = .Path & "\Email Attachments\"
  With .MailMerge
    .Destination = wdSendToNewDocument
    .SuppressBlankLines = True
    On Error Resume Next
    For i = 1 To .DataSource.RecordCount
      With .DataSource
        .FirstRecord = i
        .LastRecord = i
        .ActiveRecord = i
        If Trim(.DataFields("securitycode")) = "" Then Exit For
        StrName = "W-8BEN Form" & " - " & .DataFields("Portfoliocode") & " " & .DataFields("securitycode") & " " & .DataFields("name")
      End With
      .Execute Pause:=False
      If Err.Number = 5631 Then
        Err.Clear
        GoTo NextRecord
      End If
      For j = 1 To Len(StrNoChr)
        StrName = Replace(StrName, Mid(StrNoChr, j, 1), "_")
      Next
      StrName = Trim(StrName)
      With ActiveDocument
        .SaveAs FileName:=StrFolder & StrName & ".pdf", FileFormat:=wdFormatPDF, AddToRecentFiles:=False
        .Close SaveChanges:=False
      End With
NextRecord:
    Next i
  End With
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

MsgBox ("PDFs have been created.")
End Sub

I would like the process to cycle the number of times it need to based on the Merge Results, rather than the records in the data source.

AFAIK there are five ways to modify what gets merged - (1) change the data source altogether, (2) apply filters in the Edit Recipient List Dialog Box, (3) Deselect individual records in that dialog box, (4) filter out records using SKIP/NEXT/SKIPIF/NEXTIF fields in the Mail Merge Main Document, and (5) specify Start and Finish records in the "Finish & Merge" dialog box. With (1) and (2) a new query is issued so .RecordSource should still be correct. With (5) you might be able to do something, doubt if you can do much with (3) or (4). So which are you doing?
